# Access external url on web server

Tags: iis-6, webserver

If I log in to our web server using RDP, I can't access any of the sites we run on that web server via their external url.  For example, say my web server hosts www.example.com, when I log in to the web server, bring up a browser and try to go to www.example.com, I can't see it.

However, one of our sites was configured in some way to work like this, if I try to go to that url, it works as you might expect.

Unfortunately, this was done by our server hosting partners, who we are no longer in contact with.  Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in many way..

It depends on your network configuration, but it could also be a simple row in hosts file or a static dns record or a specific route for that ip address.

if you're using IIS you should also set the website to "listen" on the loopback interface in the bindings menu.

[image: bindings]

or, for IIS 6:

[image: iis 6]

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned I was using IIS 6.0